# Flash Application with local database (not sqlite, not air)

Tags: mysql, database, flash, actionscript-3, air

I would like to have a Flash Application (not air) to connect to a local database.

Air is not only getting unsupported by Adobe in LINUX but besides, it has serious problems and miss implementation with SQLite.

So we want to connect to a local MySQL database.
This application should be simple, so we do not want to also have an unnecessary web server (also local) to make a middle communication between the flash app and the MySQL server.

There is this driver that allow to communicate Flash with MySQL
http://code.google.com/p/assql/

Question is:

1. Is this the best approach?
2. Would it be any problem using this approach when installing the whole application to each client? (because we also in the installation should install a MySQL server).

Comment: "Air is not only getting unsupported by Adobe but besides, it has serious problems and miss implementation with sqlite." What made you write these three strong statements?

Comment: I would like to see an official release stating that Adobe are dropping Air. Link?

Comment: Stopping developing and updates for  Linux is from about a year. 
And also they have a horrible and and I'd say, "joking" API for sqlite, they didn't even add (or plan to add) structural integrity usage.
Sorry I was wrong writting in generic terms. But we try to work for all platform, and removing linux support and updates goes against are way to work :-).

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL SERVER is called a **SERVER** for a reason: It is meant to be installed on servers, not on clients. So the answer to your question is:

1) No, this is not the best approach. Not even close. You would be better off using a SQLite database (however shitty you may think it is)

2) Yes. Nobody would like installing a MySQL server on their computers just for the sake of running your application. Think of casual (non-expert) users who would need to install and configure the server just for running your app. That is the very REASON why they developed SQLite and so many languages support it.

You *should* check out http://code.google.com/p/air-sqlite/ for sqlite access in AIR (I don't know if this is the same as the inbuilt code or not, so just check that out)

Comment: Umm, sever does not indicate physical distribution :-), there is no definition in the server word that indicates that, neither in the software semantic :-).
Configuration and installation for mysql server can be done autimatically with the installer aplication, it can be done almost transparent for user :-).